# Using AND in excel rules

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use an AND in setting up a rule in excel 2010

I have

```
=$D5:$D17<=TODAY()
```

However this rule is applied to empty rows so I want to say `AND a cell != ""` (I do c#..)

How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Use the AND function? `=AND(first, second, ...)` - http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/qt/and_function.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=and($D5:$D17<=TODAY(),$D5:$D17<>"")
```

Comment: Just an extra remark, depending on your region it's possible you need to change the `,` by `;`

Answer (score 1):

check out https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-c192b0d8-0eeb-4768-a674-f84e6df9aefb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

according to the above link, the following format should do what you want:

```
AND(logical1, [logical2], ...)
```

so you could try the following:

```
=AND($D5:$D17<=TODAY(), $A1!="")
```

If you run into problems with it, make sure each individual logical test is being evaluated properly and returning an expected value. The easiest way to do that would be to store each part in different cells and just check the output.